# page wordpress add extra unwanted stuff

Tags: pages, filters, html

i want to add this part to wordpress page but every time i add it wordpress add extra     stuff that stop it from working properly this is my code

```
<li data-hovercolor="#e859c5">
                <a href="/digitalways/?page_id=308">
                    <h2 data-type="mText" class="sti-item">server</h2>
                    <h3 data-type="sText" class="sti-item"></h3>
                    <span data-type="icon" class="sti-icon sti-icon-server sti-item"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li data-hovercolor="#0f96c3">
                <a href="/digitalways/?page_id=448">
                    <h2 data-type="mText" class="sti-item">program</h2>
                    <h3 data-type="sText" class="sti-item"></h3>
                    <span data-type="icon" class="sti-icon sti-icon-hardware sti-item"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

this is how wordpress make it

```
<li data-hovercolor="#e859c5">
<a href="/digitalways/?page_id=308">
<p></p>
<h2 data-type="mText" class="sti-item">server</h2>
<h3 data-type="sText" class="sti-item"></h3></a>
<p><a><span data-type="icon" class="sti-icon sti-icon-server sti-item"></span></a></li>
            </li>
```

Comment: if you can Try to keep it in div tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your functions.php, this should give the result you're looking for:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Comment: thaaaaaaaaanks alot you are really a life saver